I have to trigger wire:click twice for the data in the page to be refreshed
I create a simple cashier system using Laravel Livewire, it has a feature to remove item from cart and reset all the item from the cart.
in the beginning everything was okay, but lately I've faced an issue that I have to click the remove or reset cart button twice for them to be refreshed, it actually been removed from the first click, the component seems to rendering the cart before delete process or I don't really understand.
Sorry for my broken English.
I have tried using updated hook and put everything in mount but it didn't work.
here's my component code
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\CartStorage;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Customer;
use App\Models\Guide;
use App\Models\Package;
use App\Models\PaymentType;
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Setting;
use App\Models\Treatment;
use Livewire\Component;

class CashierTreatment extends Component
{
    // protected $listeners = [];
    public $taxService, $paymentTypes, $categories, $customers;
    public $category_id, $guide_id, $customer_id;
    public $sub_total, $grand_total, $taxServiceValue, $payAmount, $change;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->taxService   = Setting::where('id', 1)->first()->value;
        $this->paymentTypes = PaymentType::all();
        $this->categories   = Category::all();
        $this->customers    = Customer::all();
    }

    protected function updateTotal()
    {
        $this->sub_total        = 1000;
        $this->taxServiceValue  = $this->sub_total * $this->taxService / 100;
        $this->grand_total      = $this->sub_total + $this->taxServiceValue;
    }

    public function getCategory($category_id = null)
    {
        $this->category_id = $category_id;
    }

    public function addToCart($item)
    {
        Product::find($item['id'])->decrement('stock');
        CartStorage::updateOrCreate(
            ['product_id' => $item['id']],
            ['user_id' => auth()->user()->id]
        )->increment('qty');
        $this->updateTotal();
    }

    public function incrementQty($item)
    {
        $product = Product::find($item['product']['id']);
        if ($product->stock > 0) {
            $product->decrement('stock');
            CartStorage::where('product_id', $item['product']['id'])->increment('qty');
            $this->updateTotal();
        }
    }

    public function changeQty($item, $value)
    {
        $product    = Product::find($item['product']['id']);
        $baseStock  = $product->stock + $item['qty'];
        $value      = $value > 1 ? $value : 1;
        $value      = $value > $baseStock ? $baseStock : $value;
        CartStorage::where('product_id', $product->id)->update(['qty' => $value]);
        $product->update(['stock' => $baseStock - $value]);
    }

    public function decrementQty($item)
    {
        $cartItem = CartStorage::where('product_id', $item['product']['id'])->first();
        if ($cartItem->qty > 1) {
            Product::find($item['product']['id'])->increment('stock');
            $cartItem->decrement('qty');
            $this->updateTotal();
        }
    }

    // $orderNumber = sprintf('%04d', $orderNumber);

    // $uid = Carbon::now()->format("Ymd") . $orderNumber;

    public function removeFromCart($item)
    {
        Product::find($item['product']['id'])->update(['stock' => $item['product']['stock'] + $item['qty']]);
        CartStorage::where('product_id', $item['product']['id'])->delete();
        $this->updateTotal();
        $this->render();
    }

    public function resetCart()
    {
        $cartItem   = CartStorage::all();
        foreach ($cartItem as $item) {
            Product::find($item->product_id)->update(['stock' => $item->product->stock + $item->qty]);
        }
        CartStorage::truncate();
        $this->reset(['sub_total', 'grand_total', 'taxServiceValue', 'guide_id', 'customer_id', 'payAmount']);
        $this->render();
    }

    public function rightAmount()
    {
        $this->payAmount = $this->grand_total;
    }

    public function checkout()
    {
        // 
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $categories         = $this->categories;
        $guides             = Guide::where('check_in', 1)->get();
        $customers          = $this->customers;
        $paymentTypes       = $this->paymentTypes;
        $products           = Product::with('category')
            ->whereHas('CartStorage')
            ->orWhere('stock', '>', 0)
            ->when($this->category_id, function ($query) {
                $query->where('category_id', $this->category_id);
            })
            ->get();
        $cartList           = CartStorage::with(['product', 'product.category'])->get();

        return view('livewire.cashier-treatment', compact('categories', 'products', 'guides', 'customers', 'paymentTypes', 'cartList'));
    }
}


here my view
<div class="flex flex-row h-screen">
    <div class="basis-3/4 h-dvh">
        <main class="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="flex items-baseline justify-between border-b border-gray-200 pb-6 pt-24">
              <h1 class="text-4xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900">Treatments</h1>
      
              <div class="flex items-center">
                <a href="{{ route('kasir.dashboard.index') }}" class="rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-3 py-1.5 text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600"> 
                    <span aria-hidden="true"> &larr;</span>
                    Back to Dashboard
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
      
            <section aria-labelledby="products-heading" class="pb-24 pt-6">
              <h2 id="products-heading" class="sr-only">Products</h2>
      
              <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-8 gap-y-10 lg:grid-cols-4">
                <!-- Filters -->
                <h3 class="sr-only">Categories</h3>
                <ul role="list" class="space-y-4 border-b border-gray-200 pb-6 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                    <li class="cursor-pointer px-3.5 py-2.5 @if (!$category_id)
                        rounded-md bg-gray-400
                    @endif" wire:click="getCategory()">
                        All
                    </li>
                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                    <li class="cursor-pointer px-3.5 py-2.5 @if ($category_id == $category->id)
                        rounded-md bg-gray-400
                    @endif" wire:key="{{ $category->name }}{{ $category->id }}" wire:click="getCategory({{ $category->id }})" wire:loading.class="opacity-50">
                        {{ $category->name }}
                    </li>
                @endforeach
                </ul>
      
                <!-- Product grid -->
                <div class="lg:col-span-3">
                    <fieldset class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
                        <legend class="sr-only">Delivery</legend>

                        @foreach ($products as $product)
                            <div wire:key="{{ $product->id }}" wire:click="addToCart({{ $product }})" class="cursor-pointer" wire:loading.class="opacity-50">
                                <label
                                class="flex cursor-pointer justify-between gap-4 rounded-lg border border-gray-100 bg-white p-4 text-sm font-medium shadow-sm hover:border-gray-200 has-[:checked]:border-blue-500 has-[:checked]:ring-1 has-[:checked]:ring-blue-500"
                                >
                                <div class="flex items-center gap-3">
                                  <img
                                      src="{{ asset($product->image) }}"
                                      alt="{{ $product->name }}"
                                      class="w-1/4 aspect-square rounded-lg object-cover"
                                    />
                                    <div class="w-full">
                                        <small>{{ $product->category->name }}</small>
                                        <p class="text-gray-700"><b>{{ $product->name }}</b></p>
                                        <div class="flex justify-between items-center w-full">
                                          <p class="mt-1 text-gray-900">Rp @money($product->price)</p>
                                          <p class="text-black font-bold">Stock : {{ $product->stock }}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach

                      </fieldset>
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
        </main>
    </div>
    <div class="basis-1/4">
        <div class="flex h-full flex-col overflow-y-scroll bg-white shadow-xl">
            <div class="flex-1 overflow-y-auto px-4 py-6 sm:px-6">
              <div class="flex items-start justify-between">
                <h2 class="text-lg font-medium text-gray-900" id="slide-over-title">Shopping cart</h2>
                <div class="ml-3 flex h-7 items-center">
                  
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="mt-8">
                <div class="flow-root">
                  <ul role="list" class="-my-6 divide-y divide-gray-200">
                    {{-- @if ($cartList) --}}
                      @foreach ($cartList as $cartItem)
                          <li class="flex py-6" wire:key="{{ $cartItem->product->id }}">
                              <div class="ml-4 flex flex-1 flex-col">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="flex justify-between text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                                      {{-- <small>{{ $item['treatment']['name'] }}</small> --}}
                                      <h3>
                                          <a href="#">{{ $cartItem->product->name }}</a>
                                      </h3>
                                      <p class="ml-4">Rp @money($cartItem->product->price)</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">{{ $cartItem->product->category->name }}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex flex-1 items-end justify-between text-sm">
                                    {{-- <p class="text-gray-500">{{ $item['valid_period'] ? $item['valid_period']." Month(s)" : "-" }}</p> --}}
                                    <div class="mt-2">
                                      {{-- <label for="Quantity" class="sr-only"> Quantity </label> --}}
                                    
                                      <div class="flex items-center gap-1">
                                        <button type="button" wire:click="decrementQty({{ json_encode($cartItem) }})" class="size-10 leading-10 text-gray-600 transition hover:opacity-75">
                                          &minus;
                                        </button>
                                    
                                        <input
                                          type="integer"
                                          id="input{{ $cartItem->id }}"
                                          value="{{ $cartItem->qty }}"
                                          wire:change="changeQty({{ json_encode($cartItem) }}, $event.target.value)"
                                          {{-- wire:model="cartList[{{ $cartItem }}]['qty']" --}}
                                          class="h-10 w-16 rounded border-gray-200 text-center [-moz-appearance:_textfield] sm:text-sm [&::-webkit-inner-spin-button]:m-0 [&::-webkit-inner-spin-button]:appearance-none [&::-webkit-outer-spin-button]:m-0 [&::-webkit-outer-spin-button]:appearance-none"
                                        />
                                    
                                        <button type="button" wire:click="incrementQty({{ json_encode($cartItem) }})" class="size-10 leading-10 text-gray-600 transition hover:opacity-75">
                                          &plus;
                                        </button>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex">
                                      <button type="button" wire:click="removeFromCart({{ json_encode($cartItem) }})" class="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">Remove</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                          </li>
                      @endforeach
                    {{-- @endif --}}
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="border-t border-gray-200 px-4 py-6 sm:px-6">
              {{-- <form wire:submit="checkout"> --}}

                <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-center gap-2">
                    <div class="basis-1/2">
                        <label for="HeadlineAct" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"> Customer </label>
                        <select id="HeadlineAct" wire:model="customer_id" class="mt-1.5 w-full rounded-lg border-gray-300 text-gray-700 sm:text-sm">
                          <option value="">Please select</option>
                          @foreach ($customers as $customer)
                                <option value="{{ $customer->id }}" wire:key="{{ $customer->name.$customer->id }}">
                                    {{ $customer->name }}
                                </option>
                          @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="basis-1/2">
                        <label for="HeadlineAct1" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"> Guide </label>
                        <select wire:model="guide_id" id="HeadlineAct1" class="mt-1.5 w-full rounded-lg border-gray-300 text-gray-700 sm:text-sm">
                          <option value="">Please select</option>
                          @foreach ($guides as $guide)
                                <option value="{{ $guide->id }}" wire:key="{{ $guide->name.$guide->id }}">
                                    {{ $guide->name }}
                                </option>
                          @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-2">
                  <label for="amount" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"> Pay Amount </label>
                  <input
                    type="number"
                    id="amount"
                    placeholder="Rp"
                    wire:model="payAmount"
                    value="{{ $payAmount }}"
                    class="mt-1 w-full rounded-md border-gray-200 shadow-sm sm:text-sm"
                  />
              </div>

                <div class="flex justify-between text-base font-medium text-gray-900 mt-2">
                    <p>Subtotal</p>
                    <p>Rp @money($sub_total)</p>
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-between text-base font-medium text-gray-900 mt-2">
                  <p>Tax & Services</p>
                  <p>Rp @money($taxServiceValue)</p>
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-between text-base font-medium text-gray-900 mt-2">
                    <p>Grandtotal</p>
                    <p>Rp @money($grand_total)</p>
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-between text-base font-medium text-gray-900 mt-2">
                  <p>Change</p>
                  <p>Rp @money($change)</p>
                </div>
                {{-- <p class="mt-0.5 text-sm text-gray-500">Refreshing page will reset all data.</p> --}}

                <span class="mt-6 inline-flex -space-x-px overflow-hidden rounded-md border bg-white shadow-sm w-full">
                    <button
                      type="reset"
                      wire:click="resetCart"
                      wire:loading.class="cursor-wait opacity-50"
                      class="inline-block w-1/3  px-5 py-1 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-red-600 shadow-sm hover:bg-red-700 focus:relative"
                    >
                      Reset Cart
                    </button>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      wire:click="rightAmount"
                      wire:loading.class="cursor-wait opacity-50"
                      class="inline-block w-1/3  px-5 py-1 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:relative"
                    >
                      Right Amount
                    </button>
                    <button
                      class="inline-block w-fit  px-5 py-1 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-green-600 shadow-sm hover:bg-green-700 focus:relative"
                    >
                      Submit Payment
                    </button>
                </span>
              {{-- </form> --}}

              {{-- <div class="mt-6 flex justify-center text-center text-sm text-gray-500">
                  <p>
                  or
                  <button type="button" wire:click="resetCart" class="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">
                      Remove all item
                      <span aria-hidden="true"> &rarr;</span>
                  </button>
                  </p>
              </div> --}}
          </div>
      </div>
</div>



Finally I found the answer!
by adding 'li' at the end of unique key on the element inside the foreach, like this
@foreach ($cartList->sortBy('product.name') as $key => $cartItem)
                      <li class="flex py-2" wire:key="{{ $key+1 }}li">

keys really can't be the same in a single component, even if it's in different iteration :)
